# Targeting Multiple Elements with One Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that assigns dynamic classes to my div's. This function is a  that runs on the page. After the page loads, all 10 of my primary 's have classes ".info1" or ".info2" etc...

I am trying to write a Jquery function that changes the class of the div you click on, and only that one. Here is what I have attempted:

```
$(".info" + (i ++)).click(function(){
    $(".redditPost").toggleClass("show")
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(".info" + (1 + 1)).click(function(){
    $(".redditPost").toggleClass("show")
});
```

And

```
$(".info" + (i + 1)).click(function(){
    $(".redditPost").toggleClass("show")
});
```

**EDITED MY HTML: DIV RedditPost is actually a sibling to Info's parent**

```
<div class="listrow news">
    <div class="newscontainer read">
        <div class=".info1"></div>
        <div class="redditThumbnail"></div>
        <div class="articleheader read">
    </div>
    <div class="redditPost mediumtext"></div>
</div>
```

My issue is two fold.

1. The variable selection for ".info" 1 - 10 isn't working because i doesn't have a value.
2. If I did target the correct element it would change all ".redditPost" classes instead of just targeting the nearest div.

Comment: Your problem might just be here: `<div class=".info1">`. Notice how the class is `[dot]-i-n-f-o-1`. Remove the dot.

Comment: Aside from the class name including the dot, which is incorrect, inside of your click event handler use **this** as the selector, from there access the sibling redditPost instead of all redditPosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$("[class^='info']").click(funtion(){
    $(this).parent().find('.redditPost').toggleClass("show");
});
```

Alternative:

```
$('.listrow').each(function(){
    var trigger = $(this).find("[class^='info']");
    var target = $(this).find('.redditPost');

    trigger.click(function(){
        target.toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively

$(this).siblings('.redditPost').toggleClass("show");

Comment: I had a little trouble getting this to work, but I think the error is my HTML. I edited my original comment. RedditPost is actually Info's parents sibling. Does that change the structure any?

I attempted to edit yours by doing "$(this).parent().parent().find('.redditPost').toggleClass("show");"

but that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().find('.redditPost').toggleClass("show");` should work. You could also do `$(this).parents('.listrow').find('.redditPost').toggleClass("show");` Did you remove the dot "." from `<div class=".info1">` ? Does the click event fire, check by `console.log('')` or `alert()`

Comment: I added an alternative solution, maybe a bit easier to read. Previously I did forgot to add a dot to a class selector `"[class^='.info']"`, please note that.

Comment: Using a dot won't work using that selector. Use what you had previously.

Comment: Yes @Bubblesphere is right, it's attribute selector and dot will not work. It's late over here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div[class*='info']").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".redditPost").toggleClass("show")
});
```

Explanation:

```
$("div[class*='info'])
```

Handles click for every div with a class containing the string 'info'

```
$(this).parent().find(".redditPost")
```

Gets the redditPost class of the current clicked div

Comment: This looks good! But I realized my HTML was incorrect. I edited the page, does this look any different?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `class` attribute can have several classes separated by spaces, you want to use the `.filter()` method with a `RegEx` to narrow down the element selection as follows:

```js
$('div[class*="info"]').filter(function() {
    return /\binfo\d+\b/g.test( $(this).attr('class') );
}).on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.redditPost').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.show {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listrow news">
    <div class="newscontainer read">
        <div class="info1">1</div>
        <div class="redditThumbnailinfo">2</div>
        <div class="articleheader read">3</div>
        <div class="redditPost mediumtext">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```